# Specifying different versions of lz4 package in setup.py for different versions of python

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am managing an open-source library that has to be available in both python 27-3 & 36-1.  lz4 recently released version 3.0.2 and it is only supported by python >= 3.5. Currently, I don't list a dependency on lz4 in my `setup.py` so it must be a sub-dependency of one of my dependencies.

Is the only way to do this is to force the user (trying to get the 27-3 version, which shouldn't be many) to try install my egg and once it fails to compile lz4 they can run `pip install lz4==3.0.0` manually and then try installing my pacakage again?

I know things like this are available in requirements.txt:

```
lz4<=3.0.0; python_version < '3.0'
lz4; python_version > '3.0'
```

But I try to keep all my setup instructions localized to my `setup.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies can be declared in `setup.py`, not only in `requirements.txt`. In `setup.py` use [`install_requires`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies):

```
setup(
    …
    install_requires = [
        "lz4<=3.0.0; python_version < '3.0'",
        "lz4; python_version > '3.0'",
    ]
    …
)
```

A few real-world examples: [SQLObject](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/blob/0783e77bcfe6511483f864ebb152d306d858758f/setup.py#L98), [sqlconvert](https://github.com/phdru/sqlconvert/blob/7f200e601d03cf794c5a0504a2f69da3cf1d531a/setup.py#L57).

Comment: This solved my problem, although it looks like I needed to limit it to <=2.2.1 for 27-3, not sure where I got 3.0.0 from.  One other question, if you were planning on downloading and installing this package would you rather there be a hardcoded dependency on `lz4`, like above, or would you rather be hit with the installation exception?  The only issue I can think of with the approach we're taking is if `lz4` adds support for 27-3 in >=3.0.0 and then someone tries to install this with a newer version installed it will force them to downgrade.  I'm probably worrying too much

Comment: IMO dependencies with lower/upper bounds like `lz4>2.0,<3.0.0` or just `lz4<3.0` are perfectly ok.